# Nightwatch.js using data attributes

Tags: attributes, nightwatch.js

I'm new to nightwatch.js. I work in QA and the developers don't want to use ids or classes for the automated tests. They want to use `data-test`. So for example `data-test="nav-button"`.

Is there way to find elements and click elements using this attribute in nightwatch.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple. Just put the `data-test` in square brackets after the element type. See below for examples. In these examples, the data-test attribute is in an anchor tag.

`.waitForElementVisible('a[data-test=nav-button]')
 .click(a[data-test=nav-button])`

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!